# Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file while running pentaho job through linux

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

Help me to resolve the error in pentaho kettle, please. This is error log:

```
ERROR: Bundle pentaho-webjars-deployer [10] Unable to get module class path. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.<init>(JarContent.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.getEntryAsContent(JarContent.java:294)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.calculateContentPath(BundleRevisionImpl.java:436)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.initializeContentPath(BundleRevisionImpl.java:369)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.getContentPath(BundleRevisionImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.getResourceLocal(BundleRevisionImpl.java:498)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1528)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1440)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.getBundleResource(Felix.java:1621)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getResource(BundleImpl.java:655)
    at org.apache.servicemix.specs.activator.Activator.register(Activator.java:136)
    at org.apache.servicemix.specs.activator.Activator.bundleChanged(Activator.java:104)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:869)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:790)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:515)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StatefulResolver.fireResolvedEvents(StatefulResolver.java:1126)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StatefulResolver.resolve(StatefulResolver.java:439)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3993)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.framework [0] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (java.lang.NullPointerException)
```

Comment: Spelling, formatting

Comment: This error occurs for us after updating from 7.1 to 8.0 (CE).

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the caches folders on /data-integration/system/karaf/caches/pan/ and /data-integration/system/karaf/caches/kitchen/. So after try run spoon again.